# How can I isolate list items to perform additional data manipulation?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program to help our HR department enter payroll.
The SQL query outputs a file that contains data like this:

```
1,E,REG,40.0000000
10,E,REG,11.5000000
10,E,REG,11.0000000
10,E,REG,5.5000000
10,E,REG,.0000000
10,E,REG,2.5000000
10,E,REG,3.5000000
10,E,REG,6.0000000
10,E,OT,5.5000000
10,E,OT,9.5000000
```

In VB, I have created a class called Employee

```
Public Class Employee
     Public Property empNo As Integer
     Public Property eCode As String
     Public Property webCode As String
     Public Property hrsWork As Decimal

End Class
```

I have been able to take the information from the file and load it into a list

```
Dim allEmployees = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\file\testout.txt")
                       Let Columns = line.Split(","c)
                       Where Columns.Length = 4
                       Let empNum = Integer.Parse(Columns(0).Trim())
                       Let eCode = Columns(1)
                       Let webCode = Columns(2)
                       Let hrsWrk = Decimal.Parse(Columns(3))
                       Select New Employee With {.empNo = empNum, .eCode = eCode, .webCode = webCode, .hrsWork = hrsWrk}
Dim EmpList As List(Of Employee) = allEmployees.ToList()
```

What I need to do next, is go through this list, and take the individual employees by number, and then by the webCode (REG, OT etc) and sum their hours. When this is done, I need to output them back into a txt file that HR can import into our payroll system.

The output file needs to look like this:

```
1,E,REG,40.0000000
10,E,REG,40.0000000
10,E,OT,15.0000000
```

and so on throughout the entire file.

Im really stuck on how to isolate each employee to continue.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I should think that if you used a loop and a Dictionary(Of Int32, Employee), you could add the Reg and OT values as you read the file

Comment: Do you have an example snip of code or a link to another site I can reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate the data as you read it in using a loop.  First, to make the loop simpler and as a personal preference, I made the `Employee` class smart enough to create itself:

```
Public Class Employee
    ...properties
    Public Sub New(items As String())
        empNo = Int32.Parse(items(0))
        eCode = items(1)
        webCode = items(2)
        hrsWork = Decimal.Parse(items(3))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code passes the split data to it and lets it assign the values.  Then the loop:

```
Dim eList As New List(Of Employee)
Dim line As String
Dim data() As String
Dim EmpId As Int32

Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\Temp\empsql.csv")
    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        line = sr.ReadLine
        data = line.Split(","c)

        EmpId = Int32.Parse(data(0))
        ' find an emp with matching number and this "webcode"
        Dim oldemp = eList.
                 Where(Function(w) w.empNo = EmpId AndAlso w.webCode = data(2)).
                 FirstOrDefault()

        ' if emp does not exist, create one
        If oldemp Is Nothing Then
            Dim Emp = New Employee(data)
            eList.Add(Emp)
        Else
            ' add the current hours
            oldemp.hrsWork += Decimal.Parse(data(3))
        End If
    Loop
End Using
```

Alternatively you could process the collection of raw data you create, nut rather than create items which will just have to be removed later, one extra step lets you increment the hours for any record already read.  Test result:

```
For Each emp In eList
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}   {2}   {3}", emp.empNo, emp.eCode,
                      emp.webCode, emp.hrsWork)
Next
```

Result:

> ```
> 1  E   REG   40.0000000
> 10  E   REG   40.0000000
> 10  E   OT   15.0000000
> ```

To write it back out, you could do the same thing except add commas to the format string and write to a file rather than debug window.

Note that `String.Split` is not ideal for parsing CSVs. It can fail on several common things. The [TextFieldParser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470244/1070452) is more robust, see the link for an example.  Given the source and contents you are probably safe, but it is worth mentioning for others.

Comment: Wonderful! It works great! Thanks for the help! Now to get it to output back to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a FOR EACH loop.

```
Using myWriter as new system.io.streamwriter("<Path to your output file>")
    For Each tempemployee as Employee in EmpList
         mywriter.writeline(tempemployee.empno, tempemployee.eCode, tempemployee.webCode, tempemployee.hrsWork)   
    Next
End Using
```

You code above will write a text file with the output format that you are looking for.  To explain, every iteration of the loop will make tempemployee a new value.....for example, if you have 3 employees, the first pass of the loop will have tempemployee be the first employee, then the second time, tempemployee is now the second, and then the third.